# Erro ao ler array do LocalStorage

Tags: array, angularjs, string, ionic

Olá, tenho um array e o usuário pode embaralhar a ordem dos itens:

```
Blusas = ['verde','azul','amarela','rosa','laranja','preta','roxa','vermelha',]
```

Após embaralhar, esse é o código de captura da atualização, transformando o array em uma string:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('Blusas', JSON.stringify(this.Blusas))
```

E esse é o código para salvar a atualização no OnInit:

```
this.Blusas = localStorage.getItem('Blusas');
```

No entanto, recebo esse erro sinalizado no "this.Blusas":

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não encontro solução em nenhum lugar.

Comment: está um pouco confuso, onde dá o erro, no set ou get? *"E esse é o código para salvar a atualização no OnInit"* esse código não "salva" acho seria "lê" não é? testei o set/get no navegador e funciona, não seria um problema com o this? não tem o código todo não da pra ajudar muito

Comment: Isso mesmo código de leitura. Pelo que pesquise, é como se o "this.Blusas" não fosse reconhecido como uma string e por isso, não consegue ser armazenado.

Tentei mudar para "Blusas: string = ['verde','azul','amarela','rosa','laranja','preta','roxa','vermelha'] mas o array continua não sendo reconhecido como uma string.

Comment: Algumas sugestões pra melhorar seu código... 1. Nomeie propriedades e variáveis em `camelCase`. Isto é, renomeie `Blusas` para `blusas`. 2. Evite acessar o localStorage dessa forma. O mais bacana seria você encapsular o acesso através de um serviço, o que traria várias vantagens. Maior aderência ao SRP, maior abstração, desacoplamento, facilidade nos testes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Blusas` é do tipo `string[]`. Quando você chama `localStorage.getItem('Blusas')`, é retornada a versão "stringificada" do array de blusas que você guardou no local storage. Em outras palavras - você está tentando assinalar uma string em um array de strings.

Para corrigir, basta parsear a string de volta para a sua forma de array.

```
this.Blusas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Blusas'))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolvido